# Can I use git pull --rebase instead of "git stash git pull git stash pop"?

Tags: git, rebase, git-pull, git-stash

What is the difference between

```
git pull --rebase
```

and

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest you create an experimental repo and try the commands out. Experimenting by yourself makes learning easier.

You will notice that the command sequence `git stash; git pull; git stash pop` will move **uncommitted** changes to the updated head of the master branch. (It will also do a normal merge, so committed changes will be merged, not rebased, assuming default gitconfig)

However, `git pull -rebase` will move changes which have **already been committed** to the updated head of the master branch. If you try running this command with a dirty work tree, you will see the error message:

```
Cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Please commit or stash them.
```

Comment: what I still don't understand is that some files do not get stashed, and I find myself having to move them manually outside the project, do the rebase and unstash and move those files back

Comment: @medmek Do you know about `git stash --include-untracked`?

Answer (score 6):

To answer the question in the title: No, but you can use this to achieve what you want in one command:

```
git pull --rebase --autostash
```

More info: https://cscheng.info/2017/01/26/git-tip-autostash-with-git-pull-rebase.html

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer to your question in the subject is "no".

The difference between `git pull --rebase` and `git pull` is, that the first does a `fetch` + `rebase`, the second a `fetch` + `merge`, except you have a non-default git config that tells `git pull` to do a `rebase` instead of a merge. In that case the two commands would be identical.

The difference between those two commands does not influence in any way the need to stash and unstash uncommitted changes. Both need this if you have a dirty worktree or they will error out, telling you to commit or stash your changes.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a year old post, but...

`git pull --rebase`

~ vs ~

`git stash /git pull /git stash pop`

git pull --rebase is sort of a hybrid - if you will - between the two.
It will allow you to keep your commits, and pull the most recently committed (pushed) files from your central repo. It's kinda like time travel, dude..  *explosion noise*

But to answer the question.... `Git stash` holds on to uncommitted changes, then puts 'em back after the pull is finished.

So - if you're not completely done with something, but need the newest files on the central repo, you would:

`git stash`
`git pull`
`git stash pop`

However, say you have finished something, and committed it - but your coworker Timmy who never tells anyone shit, has committed files and pushed them to the main(central) repo, you should get his stuff first, THEN add your commits to the stack, and push'em..

If you have commits, and haven't pushed your changes to the main(central) repo, and have to obtain the new files on the central repo because another dev has since committed and pushed their files - you would use:

`git pull --rebase`

Its like when you make a hamburger, but forgot to try the homemade cheese your buddy wants you to try, so here he comes with your slice and you have to take your top bun off to apply this cheese, and then put the bun back on - boom bang bing. cheeseburger.

Answer (score -2):

git pull: you actually issuing git fetch + git merge commands, which will result with an extra commit and ugly merge bubbles in your commit log.

git pull --rebase: to keep the repository clean, your commits always on top of the tree until you push them to a remote server. The command will apply all your yet-to-be-pushed commits on top of the remote tree commits allowing your commits to be straight in a row and without branches